# customizing the pop up window that comes after clicking filter button

Tags: sharepoint

in the sharepoint list filter webpart with settings as multiple selection allowed. when the filter button is clicked a pop up page appears to do the selection . how can i change the title and text on that page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is called FilterValuesPickerDialog.aspx you have to edit the file directly at the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS folder. This modification:

1) can break on SharePoint updates
2) will appear in all sites under your sharepoint server

you can create a small javascript filter to address the second problem, testing for the host:

```
if ( window.location.host == 'myhost' ) {
// change title and text
}
```